# Tomcat Error - Changing the project name to [/$%7Bproject.name%7D-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/]

Tags: spring, jsp, maven, jakarta-ee, tomcat

My Tomcat is not running my project, just the URL name of my project is being swapped for `[/ 7Bproject.name $%% 7D-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT /]`. And even directly accessing the URL of my project it does not run.

I'm using eclipse too.

The error message returned on my console is:

```
Jun 09, 2014 12:00:22 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound 
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/ 7Bproject.name $%% 7D-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT /] in DispatcherServlet with name 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet'
```

My web.xml is well:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>upload-videos</display-name>

    <!-- DEFAULT PAGE -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>views/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- SPRING MVC -->
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>
          org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
      </servlet-class>
      <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>
              /WEB-INF/spring-mvc-context.xml
          </param-value>
      </init-param>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>br.com.maycon</groupId>
    <artifactId>upload-videos</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <!-- PROPRIEDADES DO PROJETO -->
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <!-- REPOSITÓRIOS -->
    <repositories>

        <!-- SPRING REPOSITORY -->
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
            <name>EBR Spring Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release </url>
        </repository>

        <!-- SPRING REPOSITORY -->
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
            <name>EBR External Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external </url>
        </repository>

        <!-- ZENCODER REPOSITORY -->
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <!-- DEPENDÊNCIAS -->
    <dependencies>

        <!-- JAVAEE WEB API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SERVLET-API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSP-API -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SPRING WEB MVC -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SPRING CONTEXT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- SPRING CORE -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AMAZON AWS SDK -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- FILE UPLOAD -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- ZENCODER -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.brightcove.zencoder.api</groupId>
            <artifactId>zencoder-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.15</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <!-- CONFIGURAÇÕES DE CONSTRUÇÃO DO PROJETO -->
    <build>
        <!-- NOME FINAL DO PROJETO -->
        <finalName>${project.name}-${project.version}</finalName>

        <!-- PLUGINS -->
        <plugins>

            <!-- VERSÃO DO COMPILADOR DO MAVEN -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

        <!-- RECURSOS -->
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>

    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you provided the required Request mapping also verify your context root for accessing the applicaation